# <div> inside <li> is displayed incorrect in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, doctype

Here is a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    li div {
      border: 1px solid #FF0000; 
      width: 100px; 
      position:relative; 
      white-space: nowrap; 
      overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <div>111111111111111111111</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>222222222222222222222</div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

The page is displayed not as expected in IE8.

Firefox: (OK)

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/t6fexy.jpg]

IE8: (wrong)

[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/2naslqp.jpg]

Could somebody explain why?

If remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` everything will be ok, but I want to find the reason and fix it via CSS.

Comment: Try adding `li { display: block; }`.

Comment: It partially solves the problem, but the digits disappeared from the list :(

Comment: Do you have compatibility view enabled in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **position relative to 'li'** tag and change **position relative to absolute** for 'div' tag and add '**top: 0; left: 0;**' to div tag.this will work fine.

Try this css:

```
li {
  position:relative;
}
li div {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000; 
  width: 100px; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to hide all outside the borders ( http://i48.tinypic.com/21on56p.jpg )

Answer (score 2):

You could also style the div to display as an inline element:

```
li div { 
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: I had to change it to inline-block in my case, since I have block inside the div, but it works. Would be nice to know why, though